# Is the Go language built-in http server a production server?

Tags: go, webserver

I did not see that answer in the documentation, https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/.

It seems pretty complete, but typically I find the built in web servers are never recommended, such as Python, PHP, etc., for anything but development.

Comment: yes, it can be used in production.

Comment: @JimB Do you have a reference?  No offense intended.

Comment: I would say the reference is that there's nothing that says "don't use this in production". The http server is used heavily in production by lots of large companies, including Google.

Comment: In my professional experience it was the only thing used as a web server for Go development. And it worked great. If I were writing a simple API today and could choose any tools, I would use it.

Comment: FWIW I believe there are several presentations by Pike or Gerrand where they state that the golang.org web site runs on the package net/http HTTP server. I also think I've seen presentations by non-google, companies who claim they use it. Maybe search the web for gophercon or golang meetups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is a 'production' server if you use it as such. There is no reason why you would not. It is was made with the intent of you using it for real production applications, not just for testing and playing around with the language.

Comment: You will, of course, need to layer on handlers that will provide production features: security, logging, metrics etc as required in your own case.